# Vue router programmatic navigation not works

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

My programmatic navigation in the component using the vue-router is not working. After the successfull login I want redirect it to the dashboard page. But nothing happens...

Relevant code - the router:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Router from 'vue-router'
import store from '../store'
import Login from '@/components/Login'
import Dashboard from '@/components/Dashboard'

Vue.use(Router)

export default new Router({
  mode: 'history',
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/login',
      name: 'login',
      component: Login,
      beforeEnter: (to, from, next) => {
        if (store.getters.isAuthenticated) {
          // if user is already authenticated,
          // redirect it to the dashboard
          next('/dashboard') // it works
        } else {
          next()
        }
      }
    },
    {
      path: '/dashboard',
      name: 'dashboard',
      component: Dashboard,
      beforeEnter: (to, from, next) => {
        if (store.getters.isAuthenticated) {
          next()
        } else {
          // if user is not authenticated,
          // redirect it to the login
          next('/login') // it works
        }
      }
    }
  ]
})
```

Method in component:

```
userLogin () {
  this.authorizeUser({
    name: this.user.name,
    pass: this.user.pass
  }).then(result => {
    console.log('redirected to dashboard')
    this.$router.push('dashboard') // this doesn't work
  })
}
```

Package.json

```
{
  "name": "xxx",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "xxx",
  "author": "xxx",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "webpack-dev-server --inline --progress --config build/webpack.dev.conf.js",
    "start": "npm run dev",
    "lint": "eslint --ext .js,.vue src",
    "build": "node build/build.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "amazon-cognito-identity-js": "^1.31.0",
    "axios": "^0.17.1",
    "numeral": "^2.0.6",
    "sweetalert2": "^7.4.0",
    "vee-validate": "^2.0.3",
    "vue": "^2.5.2",
    "vue-router": "^3.0.1",
    "vue-slider-component": "^2.4.9",
    "vuex": "^3.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^7.1.2",
    "babel-core": "^6.22.1",
    "babel-eslint": "^8.2.1",
    "babel-helper-vue-jsx-merge-props": "^2.0.3",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.1",
    "babel-plugin-syntax-jsx": "^6.18.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.22.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-vue-jsx": "^3.5.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.3.2",
    "babel-preset-stage-2": "^6.22.0",
    "chalk": "^2.0.1",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.1",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.0",
    "eslint": "^4.15.0",
    "eslint-config-standard": "^10.2.1",
    "eslint-friendly-formatter": "^3.0.0",
    "eslint-loader": "^1.7.1",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.7.0",
    "eslint-plugin-node": "^5.2.0",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^3.4.0",
    "eslint-plugin-standard": "^3.0.1",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^4.0.0",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.0",
    "file-loader": "^1.1.4",
    "friendly-errors-webpack-plugin": "^1.6.1",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.30.1",
    "node-notifier": "^5.1.2",
    "optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "ora": "^1.2.0",
    "portfinder": "^1.0.13",
    "postcss-import": "^11.0.0",
    "postcss-loader": "^2.0.8",
    "postcss-url": "^7.2.1",
    "rimraf": "^2.6.0",
    "semver": "^5.3.0",
    "shelljs": "^0.7.6",
    "uglifyjs-webpack-plugin": "^1.1.1",
    "url-loader": "^0.5.8",
    "vue-loader": "^13.3.0",
    "vue-style-loader": "^3.0.1",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.5.2",
    "webpack": "^3.6.0",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^2.9.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.9.1",
    "webpack-merge": "^4.1.0"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">= 6.0.0",
    "npm": ">= 3.0.0"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions",
    "not ie <= 8"
  ]
}
```

No errors there, but no action is taken also - I'm still staying on the login page. What am I missing?

EDIT:

This works: this.$router.go('dashboard') Does it mean I'm using the old version?

Comment: Regarding your last edit, show us your `package.json` file.

Comment: @webnoob package.json added

Comment: Your versions are fine. I think you'll find that `.go` is only working by accident as that method takes an interger as a param and navigates to the route with that index. I think the issue you have is you're missing the `/` before your route. Try `this.$router.push('/dashboard')`

Comment: @webnoob Unfortunately, you are wrong. I din't miss anything, its from the official documentation. So, this.$router.push('/dashboard'), or  this.$router.push({ path: '/dashboard' }) doesn't work. And in previous versions of vue-router I saw usage like this this.$router.go('dashboard'), this is why I have suspicion I am using old version. I have really no idea what is happening...

Comment: In that case, to try that theory: `npm remove -s vue-router` and then `npm i -s vue-router` and see if it installs the latest version and works.

Comment: going to try it

Comment: @webnoob Still the same, no combination works: this.$router.push('dashboard'), this.$router.push('/dashboard'), this.$router.push({path: 'dashboard'}), this.$router.push({path: '/dashboard'})

Comment: Are you getting any errors in console? If you `console.log(this.$router)` do you have a `push` method? Are you able to put a break point on your `push` call and follow the method to see what's being called?

Comment: @webnoob There is no error, so push method must exists. But I tried this: this.$router.push('dashboard', _ => console.log('complete'), _ => console.log('cancelled')) with and without slash in path, and I obtain "canceled" in log everytime.

Comment: Can you try removing your `beforeEnter` handler on the `dashboard` route and see if that makes any difference?

Comment: @webnoob Bingo bro! Conflict, thanks for heading me to the right direction :) Write it as answer, I will approve it.

Comment: Glad you got it sorted :) I've popped an answer on - would be useful to add a comment to it explain why the conflict happened if it could help someone else.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your approach to redirecting is correct and `this.$router.push('dashboard')` is the correct approach. With that in mind and based on our other tests, remove your `beforeEnter` from the route as this is the last point in the chain that could cause a problem and stop the redirect.

You'll have to isolate the issue as to why that's not working separately.

Comment: I have suspicion, but no evidence yet. When I will be sure what exactly causes this behavior, I will comment or modify your answer.

Answer (score 7):

Try this:

```
this.$router.push({ path: '/dashboard' })
```

At least this works for me.

Comment: Did not help :/

Comment: I forgot the slash before dashboard. Pls try again.

Comment: I tried it before, multiple combinations. Nothing works.

Answer (score 1):

What's happening is that you are calling `this.$router` inside of a `result => { }` context so `this` is relative to that function. You have to save `this` from the outside context for it to work.

Put this `const router = this.$router;` before `this.authorizeUser({` and then `router.push('dashboard');` and then it will work.